# MongoDB storing (bulk) gps position data

Tags: mongodb, collections, bulk

I am suddenly thrown into a situation where I need to design a database for storing bulk position data coming by means of a web hook. The data that I receive at the moment has the following 5 fields(id,code,gpsdata,geojson,timestamp). The sample data is shown below

```
id=359756443722314
code=0x0000
gpsdata=$STXDE,164745.000,A,0108.6383,N,10137.8458,E,0.00,0.00,310316,,*01
geojson="geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [67.985953282709247, 29.457378472183443]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {}
timestamp="2010-07-20T23:23:50Z"
```

I have already gotten an instance of MongoDB working and thinking what would be the best way to store this information. Please note that I am a total newbie to MongoDB and the records may run into hundreds of thousands...and perhaps million of records in due course. I am thinking do I just create a single collection, or multiple collections and insert these as documents? If yes then anything to note between multiple collections vs embedded documents etc? Is it good to create a schema first or something? Sori MongoDB is totally alien to me. And as I write this I am also reading up on stuff but a few words of advise from experienced people will be greatly helpful so that I may avoid some mistakes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can store your information in a single collection. It's not a problem for MongoDB. You don't have to use schema. You can find out about geospatial information in MongoDB here https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/